# WPF Automatic Build and Reload when source code change

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I see some answer about it, suggest use Live Unit Testing feature.
So I don't have Microsoft Enterprise and therefore can't use its Live Unit Testing feature. Tried to create a simple application in order to compile & reload into the WPF container window.

skeleton code look like:

```
public void RecompileAndReloadPrj ()
{
   Grid.Content = null;
   ReleaseAsm()
   RunMsBuild(targetProject);
   Grid.Content = LoadComponetFromAsm(targetASM);
}
```

Unfortunately getting it to work has turned out to be a bit complicated... Does anyone have ready code that they could post, tips etc, or provide a link?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Compilation is expensive.  On any but the smallest most trivial project it'd be a nuisance to re-compile every time you save.  You could maybe do something with karma or chutzpah and node running msbuild. But I have serious doubts about live-reload in your designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, before couple years I wrote some code for WPF like you wish. But it's very basic and have a lot of issues around it. 
But I suggest you, check the feature of Edit XAML while debugging. It's work well even without breakpoint. Just run project under debugging mode and edit the XAML file, even if your code load it by code behind. Even Save not required.

I list here the code and some comment about it:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="RebuildAndReloadWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RebuildAndReloadWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Activated="Window_Activated" >
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>


            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" >
            <StackPanel x:Name="___No_Name_" Background="LightYellow" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Click="Button_Click" >Reload</Button>
               <CheckBox x:Name="chkReloadOnFocus" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Reload on focus" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtIndicator" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                <Border x:Name="elmJustNowIndicator" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Orange" CornerRadius="5" Height="21" Width="76" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Just now" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PlaceHolder" Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace RebuildAndReloadWPF
{
    /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const string projectPath = @"C:\...\Some-Project.csproj";
        const string libFileName = "Some-Lib.dll";
        const string ClassName = "NameSpace.UserControlName";


        private string projectFileName;
        private string projectDirectoryPath;
        private string projectBinPath;
        private string logFilePath;
        private string appDirectoryPath;
        private DispatcherTimer indicatorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();


        public MainWindow ()
        {
            projectFileName = Path.GetFileName(projectPath);
            projectDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(projectPath);
            projectBinPath = projectDirectoryPath + @"\bin\Debug";
            logFilePath = projectDirectoryPath + @"\bin\Debug\build.log";
            appDirectoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            indicatorTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            indicatorTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000);
            indicatorTimer.Tick += ( sender, e ) =>
            {
                elmJustNowIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                indicatorTimer.IsEnabled = false;
            };

            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void ReloadContainer ()
        {
            PlaceHolder.Content = null;

            bool result = RunMsBuild();

            if (!result)
            {
                txtIndicator.Text = "Compile error, see in log file. Compile fail at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                txtIndicator.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                txtIndicator.Text = "Last build at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                txtIndicator.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            }

            try
            {
                File.Copy(projectBinPath + @"\" + libFileName, appDirectoryPath + libFileName, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't copy compiled lib file: " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

            elmJustNowIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            indicatorTimer.IsEnabled = false;
            indicatorTimer.IsEnabled = true;

            try
            {
                PlaceHolder.Content = AsmLoad();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Laod assembly error" + ex.Message);
            }

            GC.Collect();
        }


        public bool RunMsBuild ()
        {
            Engine eng = new Engine();

            FileLogger logger = new FileLogger();
            logger.Parameters = "logfile=" + logFilePath;
            eng.RegisterLogger(logger);

            bool bb = eng.BuildProjectFile(projectPath);
            eng.UnregisterAllLoggers();
            return bb;
        }

        public FrameworkElement AsmLoad ()
        {
            byte[] assemblyFileBUffer = File.ReadAllBytes(appDirectoryPath + @"\" + libFileName);
            Assembly asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assemblyFileBUffer);
            ContentControl container = (ContentControl)asm.CreateInstance(ClassName);
            return (FrameworkElement)container.Content;
        }


        private void Window_Activated ( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            if (chkReloadOnFocus.IsChecked == true)
                ReloadContainer();
        }

        private void Button_Click ( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            ReloadContainer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comments:

1. The above code is work only against UserControl class. You can
   expand code to support also with Windows and Panel.
2. The above code make rebuild only when window of our app activated
   (focus). You can expand it to respond file save. By use with
   FileSystemWatcher. Notice, the watcher run event for every file. So
   you need wait after all event burst end (brobebly by timer), and
   also Suggest to configure Visual Studio to make always SaveALL for
   Ctr+S key combination.
3. Microsoft replace Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine with newest assembly
   and suggest use with new Microsoft.Build. I realize that newest have
   problem find the newest Tools (MSBuild.exe) like version 15.0. You
   probably will get error that need workaround: 
   Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The tools
   version "15.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "12.0",
   "14.0", "2.0", "3.5", "4.0".'
4. Dotnet can't release assembly after loading it dynamically. Work
   around not worth the effort. I check the above code and I run it
   with loop, the consume RAM is better than I was imagined. And also,
   I realize that Core 3.0 have solution for that. So if you like this
   code, I suggest you try emigrate it to core 3.0
5. Performance. I not try it on real project. But if you have spare RAM
   and strong CPU I believe that work well for small project, and not
   have delay more than half of second. I compare it against start
   debugging after code change. The Visual studio  have a long delay to
   enter debug mode and exit. So may you get significate improvement.
6. By the way, if you copy the debug info file (.pdb) as well as lib
   file, the VS will open the source file when runtime error occur on
   target projects. But this file get Lock. And next reload Fail (It's
   weird, but according my check, it's not happened if target project
   is VB).
7. If you really want develop with this approach. You need build your
   target app as collection of small project. You can Embedded the
   below code in your target project and open the container window when
   you on develop mode. You can add Cache system for all data read from
   files or outside resources like Databases. And Build system that
   allow jump the reload directly to some point in the Interface.